# Splitting up the Response from a server that has been derieved from JSON Object

Tags: android

I've a task to split apart the response from a web server after User Name and password have been passed.

I've attached an image that will throw some more light in my problem
[image: Logcat]

As you can see in the highlighted  line I want to retrieve each parameter separately and display it on logcat. What type of functions should I be using? Also some link to provide me with an example would be much helpful.

Cheers

Comment: did you use json parsing to read response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what you've written I am presuming your getting the response from the server as a JSONObject and you want to pass that.

If you are using JSONObject then

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("resultString"); 
JSONObject sessionJson =  jsonObj.getJSONObject("session");
String sessionId = sessionJson.getString("sessionid");
String name = sessionJson.getString("name");
Log.v("The name is"+name,"The session id is "+sessionId);
```

Here resultString is the the JSONObject that you will be recieving as a reponse from the server. The first part of the parse that you need to do is stored in "sessionJson"

```
{"session":{"sessionid":"0x000000000176f141:1000:125","name":"Andreas Öh"}}
```

Your second part i.e from "sessionid" will be stored in sessionId, and it goes on till you get the name.

Hope you find the explanation useful.
Good luck !

Answer (score 2):

you can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for achieving the same **[EXAMPLE](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-parsing-json-data-with-gson/)**

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started:

```
JSONObject object=null;
try {
    object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();

    JSONObject session=object.getJSONObject("session");
    String sessionid=session.getString("sessionid");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`JSON`](http://json.org/java/).

In your case you can retrieve the name and sessionid like this :

```
     //Get the session json
     JSONObject respJson=new JSONObject(resonseString).getJSONObject("session");
     String name=respJson.getString("name");
     String sessionId=respJson.getString("sessionId");
```